# $(x^2-9)^{(3x+5)}=(x-3)^{(x-1)}(x+3)^{(x-1)}$ What is $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(x^2-9)^{(3x+5)}=(x-3)^{(x-1)}(x+3)^{(x-1)}$
$(x^2-9)^{(3x+5)}=(x^2-9)^{(x-1)}$

$3x+5=x-1$
$x=-3$

But when I try to use WolfarmAlpha the integer solution is $3$ instead of $-3$. The numerical solution is $x\approx 3.1622776600...$

So I tried to do other things, such as making sure the base is larger than $0$.
$x^2-9>0$
$x<-3$ or $x>3$

But I still didn't obtain the $x$.
So what is $x$?

Comment: Theese are just lines without meaning if you do no specify what you are doing and why you are going on like that.

Comment: Hi @Gabrielek I edited it and tried to explain why.

Comment: Please [edit] this interesting question to tell us where it comes from. Wolfram Alpha provides that "solution" but says it has run out of computing time. What makes you think there is a solution?

Comment: Hi @EthanBolker, does that mean that it wasn't the solution, but it shows 3 as the solution because it has ran out of running time? Does that mean there is no solution instead? I'm sorry I don't understand.

Comment: @FiorellaSusanto I don't know. $3$ is a solution only because you then have $0$ on both sides of the equation. I suspect if you check the $3.16...$ "solution" with a calculator it won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation:
$$(x^2-9)^{(3x+5)}=(x^2-9)^{(x-1)}
$$
obviously holds if $x^2-9=0$ provided that the exponents are non-negative. This is the case for $x=3$.

If $x^2-9\ne0$ we can divide both sides by $(x^2-9)^{(x-1)}$ obtaining:

$$(x^2-9)^{(2x+6)}=1.$$

This equation holds if $2x+6=0$ or $x^2-9=1$. The roots of the equations are $x=-3$ and $x=\pm\sqrt{10}$, respectively.

The substitution in the original equation shows that
$x=3,\sqrt{10}$ satisfy the equation whereas the roots $x=-3,-\sqrt{10}$ do not suit it.

Comment: How do you obtain $x=3$? $x^2-9=1$ gives $x=\pm \sqrt{10}$ and $2x+6=0$ gives $x=-3$.

Comment: The last equation was obtained in the assumption $x^2-9\ne0$. If one considers the opposite case one obtains the solutions $\pm3$. I thought you have already considered the case and therefore omitted this step. If you insist I can include it as well.

Comment: Would you mind? I don't want to misunderstand anything.

Comment: I have edited the answer. If you need further clarifications don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Why do we consider the opposite case (instead the current $(x^2-9)\ne 0$)?

Comment: Because we have two cases $x^2-9=0$ and $x^2-9\ne0$. Both of them can bring solutions. And it appears that both do.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

I assume you are looking for real solution.

First, check the cases:

a) $(x^2-9)\in \{-1,0,1\}$. Test each case in the inital equation;

b) When $(x^2-9)>0$ you do $3x+5=x-1$, and take the intersection.

An observation, if you try $x=-3$ in the first equation, the term $(x-3)^{x-1}$ is equal to $(-6)^{-4}$. Is it a solution?

**EDIT**:
Plotting both functions (RHS and LHS) it seems we have two intersection. One at $x=3$ an other close to it. @user showed how to find the second solution.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused. 
The $(-6)^{(-4)}$ will be multipled with 0 on the RHS. 
I'm sorry I don't understand.

Comment: I just realised if I try $x=-3$ the LHS will be $0^{-4}=\frac{1}{0^4}=\frac{1}{0}=\infty$.

Comment: @FiorellaSusanto, please, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

The domain is $x\ge3$ due to the power functions involved, and it may easier to examine the equation with $x=t+3$, which leads to

$$(t^2+6t)^{t+2}[( t^2+6t)^{2(t+6)} -1]=0$$

The first factor produces the solution $t=0$, or $x=3$, and the second factor reduces to $t^2+6t=1$,
which yields $t=\sqrt{10}-3$, or $x=\sqrt{10}$.